# NSString memory leak when parsing xml

Tags: objective-c, parsing, memory-leaks, nsstring

am writing an application that parses some xml and creates a dictionary of the element names and their values using the below key methods:

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    foundCharacters = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 
    if (accumulator) {
        [foundCharacters appendString:string];
    }
} 

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName { 

    if ([foundCharacters length] != 0) {

                    [parsedContent setObject:[foundCharacters copy] forKey:elementName];

                }
}
```

The leak occurs in the occurs on the "[parsedContent setObject:[foundCharacters copy] forKey:elementName];" line, I can't work out a way to overcome this.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Edit:

The memory leak only occurs if the request to parse is called more than once

I've also tried "[[foundCharacters copy] autorelease]" but no to avale

Comment: Where do you release foundCharacters.

Comment: In the above code I am releasing it in my dealloc method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `parserDidStartDocument:` you alloc/init a mutable string, but I don't see code where you dispose of this string again. You need to release the string again, for example in the `parserDidEndDocument:` method.

The memory leak is reported later probably because this is the last place where the variable was actually referenced.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that help. I was releasing the string in my dealloc method but I moved it to the parserDidEndDocument:, sadly I still get the memory leak. Is it possible that its how am using the dictionary that is causing the memory leak?

Comment: Hmm, if you apply both what brindy and I mentioned, then I don't see any memory leak in the code you posted.

Comment: It seems really strange to be I can't work it out, if I do what brindy suggests or what I posted above I get a memory leak with a responsible frame "NSCFString copywithzone:". The way the application works is that I parse through the xml filling a nsmutabledictionary for each "object", adding that object to an array when I reach the end of that object's xml. When the end of document is reached I send out a notification with that array to be pocessed into data objects. I wanted to abstract the data objects from the parsing process.

Comment: thanks for your effort I finally managed to solve it. It turned out that it wasn't a memory leak with the above code but rather code that transformed to above dictionary into an object

Answer (score 3):

"copy" methods are treated like alloc/init, you're responsible for releasing them.  See here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/copy

so change your code to:

```
NSString *copy = [foundCharacters copy];
[parsedContent setObject:copy forKey:elementName];
[copy release];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply brindy, sadly I get a memory leak on the "NSString *copy = [foundCharacters copy];" line

Comment: parsedContent is a NSMutableDictionary, with the setObject being the default method that comes with it

Comment: On NSString, copy doesn't perform an actual copy, it is still a pointer to the content of the other NSString since an NSString is expected to be immutable. People should use NSMutableString more.

Comment: @mirage: Yes, but copy still then retains the original object, so you still need to release a copied object again. Also the string which is copied here is in fact a NSMutableString, and therefore copy creates a new object.

Comment: thanks for your effort I finally managed to solve it. It turned out that it wasn't a memory leak with the above code but rather code that transformed to above dictionary into an object